# Losing type information when passing an object through a System.Collections.Queue

Tags: collections, powershell, types, runtime

As part of my Powershell script I need to, essentially, implement breadth-first search. So, I need queue and figured System.Collections.Queue is as good as any other queue. However, when I get an object out of the queue, Powershell loses track of any properties I've added to the object.

What's going on here? How do I access my property?

This sample demonstrates the problem:

```
$object = new-object object
add-member -membertype noteproperty -name AnInteger -value 2 -inputobject $object
$queue = new-object system.collections.queue
$queue.enqueue($object)
$dequeued = $queue.dequeue()

# 1. True - both variables refer to the same object.
$object -eq $dequeued 
# 2. True - using the original variable, can access the property.
$object.AnInteger -ne $null
# 3. False. Err, What?
$dequeued.AnInteger -ne $null
```

## Solution and More Questions

I found my mistake: `add-member` modifies an instance of `PSObject` not Object. It looks like it created one for me to wrap `$object` before adding the property. So, I needed to either create a `PSObject` or cast the result of dequeue to `PSObject`.

I still don't understand everything that's going on here. Did `add-member` modify `$object` to refer to the `PSObject` it created? If not, how did the Powershell run-time know that `$object` was in fact a `PSObject`? `$object.gettype().name` is `Object` not `PSCustomObject`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use PsObject, it works. However, I have no idea why it doesn't work on the .NET Object

```
$object = new-object PsObject -property @{AnInteger=2}
$queue = new-object system.collections.queue
$queue.enqueue($object)
$dequeued = $queue.dequeue()

$object.Aninteger -eq $dequeued.AnInteger # returns True
```

The same holds obviously for other .NET collections as well:

```
$mynum  = 10 | add-member noteproperty MySecret 12345 -pass
$mynum.mysecret
$list = New-Object collections.arraylist
$list.Add($mynum)
$list[0].mysecret

$list[0] | fl * -force # shows nothing
$mynum | fl * -force   # shows mysecret
```

Comment: Add-Member can only directly modify PSObjects as those are the ones that can have type extensions.  To modify regular objects, use -PassThru and grab the new object.  `$Object = Add-Member -input $Object ... -PassThru`.  This will actually create a PSObject to wrap the regular object.  The new PSObject will be essentially transparent to you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that dequeue() is actually creating a new object, based on the original object type to pass back to you, which means that added properties won't be included in the returned object.  It's kind of ugly, and I don't know if it helps or not, but I did get it to work by serializing the object going into the queue, and de-serializing it when it comes back out

```
$object = new-object object
add-member -membertype noteproperty -name AnInteger -value 2 -inputobject $object
$queue = new-object system.collections.queue
$queue.enqueue((convertto-csv $object))
$dequeued = convertfrom-csv $queue.dequeue()
$dequeued



 AnInteger
 ---------
 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK, just change the first line

```
$object = new-object PSObject
```

You are perhaps a C# developper that's why you code object in spite of PSObject. I'am not sure to really understand why but PSObject has got the necessery code to keep noteproperties.

In order to write less lines you can also write the following to create `PSCustomObject`:

```
$object = "" | select AnInteger,Astring
$object.AnInteger = 12
$object.AString = "coucou"
```

The result :

```
PS> $object.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                     BaseType 
-------- -------- ----                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject           System.Object
```

It works in your code :

```
$queue = new-object system.collections.queue
$queue.enqueue($object)
$dequeued = $queue.dequeue()

$dequeued
$dequeued.AnInteger
$dequeued.Astring
```

It will give

```
AnInteger Astring                                                                        
--------- -------                                                                        
       12  coucou                                                                         
12
coucou
```