# How to overwrite object property - powershell

Tags: powershell

I am working on PSCustomObject with powershell script.

here is my code.

```
$rebootlist = @()
$rebootlist += New-Object psobject -Property @{db = "db001"; Reboot = "true"; Moniter = "true" ; RetryCount = 0 ; Status = "initial" }
$rebootlist += New-Object psobject -Property @{db = "db002"; Reboot = "true"; Moniter = "true" ; RetryCount = 0 ; Status = "initial" }
$rebootlist += New-Object psobject -Property @{db = "db003"; Reboot = "true"; Moniter = "true" ; RetryCount = 0 ; Status = "initial" }


$q = [System.Collections.Generic.Queue[array]]::new()
foreach ($x in $rebootlist) {
    $x.Status = "queued"
    $q.Enqueue($target)
}

do {
    try {
        $target = $q.Dequeue()
        
         --- DB reboot operation here abbreviated---

    catch {
        # if chach exception then put back queue to retry
        Write-Output $_.Exception
        $target.RetryCount++　　   #this line dose not work!
        $target.Status = "queued"  #this line dose not work!
        $q.Enqueue($target)
    }
        
} while ($q.count -ge 1)
```

first of all, I create $rebootlist as PSCustomObject. This $rebootlist is editable. if I want to overwrite RetryCount property. `$rebootlist[0].RetryCount=1` can overwrite RetryCount property of index 0 in $rebootlist.

$x object in foreach statement is also editable. I overwrite Status property and `$x.Status = "queued"` works fine. But once I enqueue elements in $q object and dequeue element to put a new object $target. Then $target is not editable.

`$target.RetryCount++` returns following error

```
Property 'RetryCount' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:1 char:1
+ $target.RetryCount = "2"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

please anyone tell me how to create $target objet as settable.

thanks

Comment: `$target` is not defined when your `foreach` runs. The first iteration of your `try` will error because `$q` is empty. Therefore `$target` won't get set there either. Maybe you meant to use `$q.Enqueue($x)` in your `foreach`.

Comment: This has some relevant info https://stackoverflow.com/a/6146257/2975396

Comment: Change `[System.Collections.Generic.Queue[array]]` to `[System.Collections.Generic.Queue[psobject]]` - it's not a queue of arrays, it's a queue of PSObject's

Comment: Thank you for your comment! ```[System.Collections.Generic.Queue[psobject]]``` worked perfectly!